# XPath to ignore text within an element?

Tags: xml, xpath, import.io

On this website: http://www.yankeecandle.com/browse/candles/jar-candles/_/N-9yf[image]

Using import.io to get data from the page.

I'm looking for an XPath that gets me only the lowest price, so the 10.99 and the 12.50.

[image]

I cant seem to NOT include the text in span.

`.//div[@class="prod-details"]/p[3]`

gets me all the price

`.//div[@class="prod-details"]/p[3][not(span)]`

ignores not only the span text, but also the text within the class="sl-prce price"

So the question is, can I get from the screenshot, the "sale 12.50" and NOT the 24.99 that is in the span.

Can this be done without applying Regex?

Comment: `//div[@class="prod-details"]/p[3]/text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//div[@class="prod-details"]/p[3]/text()
```